# Unable to Access Drupal site after mounting AWS EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal, drupal-7, aws-cloudformation, amazon-efs

I'm trying to install Drupal 7.x on AWS. I'm, able to install the Drupal but after adding AWS EFS mount points my site is down. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqqia.png)I can able to access the Drupal admin page but after login to the site with admin credentials, I'm effecting with the following error.

ERROR: The requested URL /node was not found on this server.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe .htaccess rewrite module is not working (properly)? What happens if you try to open i.e. some image file?

Answer (score 0):

Is the .htaccess file still present in the webroot and does it have the correct permissions?

I generally get the stock 'page not found' errors when either the htaccess is missing or mod_rewrite isn't enabled within PHP.

When you hit the login URL (/user) do you get a similar error? curious as to how you managed to login as an admin.

Comment: Admin page also not working after logging as admin I'm effecting with the error.